# New column based on rule from another (contains a number in the values)

Tags: python

I want to make a new column(b), with labels based on the values from another column(a). column a has entries that are all unique (they are file names) so I need to define it using part of the file name. I tried to use a def/if function but can't work out how to write 'if file name contains...xxx..then label it xxx; rather than if filename==xxx.

Example below with what I tried:

```
df


FileName    
C3_828_blahblahblah1.cvs    
C3_828_blahblahblah3.cvs

C3_831_blahblahblah2.cvs

C3_c3_blahblahblah1.cvs
 
C3_c4_blahblahblah2.cvs

C3_c4_blahblahblah3.cvs
 
C3_831_blahblahblah.cvs      


def CellType(c):
  if c['FileName'] = 828:
    return 'mutant1'
  elif c['FileName'] = 831:
    return 'Mutant2'
  else:
    return 'Control'



df['CellTyple'] = df.apply(CellType, axis=1)
```

Comment: Did you try using double `==` for the comparison? What you're doing there is assigning the value 828 to `c['FileName']`

Comment: hi! thanks for reply - yes, I first tried == but that just created a column with 'Control' for everything as none of the str in the column FileName is simply 828 or 831...if that makes sense; they contain the number but has other characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the different values to the new column filtering by each of your search strings:

```
# First, create the case not related to a specific condition with the value 'control'
df['CellType'] = 'control'

# Filter the dataframe by your conditions and add the appropriate values
df.loc[df['filename'].str.contains("828"),'CellType'] = 'mutant1'
df.loc[df['filename'].str.contains("831"),'CellType'] = 'mutant2'
```

Comment: amazing @Carlos Melus! so much simpler than my original idea! thanks so much!